# stored procedure cannot loop an array of string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$StupidArray = "Boys, are, not, smiling, at, all,";

if (!$db->query(" SET @msg = ''; SET @Stringarray = '\' $StupidArray '\'; " ) 
    || !$db->query(" CALL StupidProcedure (@Stringarray, @msg)") )
{
    echo "CALL to StupidProcedure failed:".print_r($db->errorInfo()); 

}
else
{
    $res = $db->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out");
    $row = $res->fetch();
    print_r($row['_p_out']);
}
```

I have this mysql stored procedure that should loop through an arbitrary array of strings.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StupidProcedure (INOUT Stringarray VARCHAR(100), IN msg VARCHAR (100) )

BEGIN

    /*Table loop variable*/
    DECLARE indx INT;
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE valu INT;

    SET @indx = 0;
    SET @len = 0;

    WHILE LOCATE(',', @Stringarray , @indx + 1) > 0 DO
        SET @len = LOCATE(',', @Stringarray , @indx + 1) - @indx;
        SET @valu = SUBSTRING(@Stringarray , @indx, @len);

        SELECT CONCAT(@msg, @valu) INTO msg; /* For Debugging purpose*/

        SET @indx = LOCATE(',', @Stringarray , @indx + @len) + 1; /*increment loop*/

    END WHILE;         
END
```

Now, I needed to be sure that concatenated `@msg` has received all data in `@Stringarray` after the loop. Using php, I simply did this:

```
$StupidArray = "Boys, are, not, smiling, at, all,";
if (!$db->query(" SET @msg = ''; SET @Stringarray = '\' $StupidArray '\'; "  )) 
{
    echo "CALL to StupidProcedure failed:".print_r($db->errorInfo());    
}
else
{
    $res = $db->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out");
    $row = $res->fetch();
    print_r($row['_p_out']);
}​
```

What I got in return was `all`, the last is `$StupidArray`.
What am I doing wrong? OR is it my loop that is failing?

Comment: what call? You don't actually call your sproc... you're just setting some @vars.

Comment: sorry for  that . its been updated

Comment: you can't run multiple statements in a single query call, so your first call is probably failing, returning boolean false, which prevents your call() query from ever being executed.

Comment: @Mark  am sorry for that, its my text editor that seem to be failing as this is not the actual place of test. the bottom line is that a call was made and only the last element of my array was returned. what's the way out if you know ?